# As we know Crabbe and Goyle Sr were both Death Eaters: What were their jobs in the magical world?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

Did people know that Crabbe and Goyle Sr were Death Eaters? What were their jobs in the magical world?

Comment: Maybe they worked as gamekeepers at Malfoy manor... :D

Comment: VTC-ers - where does "opinion" come into this? Either they were, they weren't, or there was no evidence of either case.

Comment: Their job in the magical world was probably "Upper Class Twit".  That's a fairly stock character in British fiction.

Answer (score 9):

There's no canon info (I checked Accio Quote, searched the books, googled, checked Wikia, Pottermore and jkrowling.com).

However, we can surmise that they likely worked for Malfoys, as Draco knows their kids from the get-go (they act as Dracos hired muscle on the train to Hogwarts):

> "Yes," said Harry. He was looking at the other boys. Both of them were
>   thickset and looked extremely mean. Standing on either side of the pale
>   boy, they looked like bodyguards.
>   "Oh, this is Crabbe and this is Goyle," said the pale boy carelessly,
>   noticing where Harry was looking. "And my name's Malfoy, Draco Malfoy."
>   (*PS, Ch 6, "The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters"*)

Note that this is a typical arrangement for European nobility - the kids of the thugs/retainers for a father nobleman become the same for the nobleman's kid.

**If** they worked for Lucius Malfoy, we don't know what they did but some sort of enforcers wouldn't be out of realm of possibility; if their kids are anything like them they aren't very bright/skilled otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I can guarantee that people didn't know they were Death Eaters - they were acquitted. In the scene where Fudge turns up in the hospital wing in *The Goblet of Fire*, just after Barty Crouch Jr has suffered the Dementor's kiss and Dumbledore and Fudge have their argument, we get this:

> 'Look, I saw Voldemort come back!' Harry shouted. He tried to get out of bed again, but Mrs Weasley forced him back. 'I saw the Death Eaters! I can give you their names! Lucius Malfoy -'
>
> ...
>
> 'Avery - Nott - Crabbe - Goyle -'
>
> 'You are merely repeating the names of those who were acquitted of being Death Eaters thirteen years ago!' said Fudge angrily. 'You could have found those names in old reports of the trials! ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.613 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 36, *The Parting of the Ways*

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference of them having a job outside of being Death Eaters. Unless they were caught during the first war, which I would say they weren't on the fact that they would be in Azkaban, no one knew that they were Death Eaters.

Now from context clues from the books and relationships between them and the Malfoys I would say they probably worked closely with Lucius Malfoy, and at the end of the war with his money probably did a plea bargain saying some names and stating that they were confused and just loosely associated with Voldemort. I would also say it wouldn't be hard to see them actually work for Malfoy as thugs/heavy lifters for professional jobs, as Draco acts like he owns the kids, and they are always described us big and dull.

Answer (score 1):

I searched the web and the books but could find limited information about Crabbe Sr. and Goyle Sr. My best guess would be that they didn't have one, since most pure-blood families are very wealthy. I also looked on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com) and found that they were listed in the Sacred 28, a list of all the wizarding families still considered "pure" by the 1930's to 1940's. So assuming they didn't end up like the Gaunts or Weasleys, it is very possible that they lived off of a family fortune, like Lucius Malfoy.

Answer (score 1):

## They likely were ‘respectable’ - the Malfoys associated with them.

Though it’s not clear what either Crabbe’s or Goyle’s jobs were, or even if they had joined or were independently wealthy, Crabbe can be presumed to have a respectable position. Lucius Malfoy was willing to both associate with him himself, and let his son associate with and befriend Crabbe’s son before they began attending Hogwarts. This implies Crabbe likely didn’t have a ‘lower class’ job.

> In childhood, Draco associated mainly with the pure-blood children of his father’s ex-Death Eater cronies, and therefore arrived at Hogwarts with a small gang of friends already made, including Theodore Nott and Vincent Crabbe. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Draco Malfoy (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy)*</sup></sub>

Though Goyle’s son only met Draco at Hogwarts, he likely did too, since it’s unlikely that Draco would choose to befriend someone that his father would disapprove of.

> It was, therefore, in the knowledge that he was doing nothing of which his father would disapprove, and in the hope that he might be able to relay some interesting news home, that Draco Malfoy offered Harry Potter his hand when he realised who he was on the Hogwarts Express. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Draco Malfoy (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy)*</sup></sub>

Since Draco very heavily patterned himself after his father, it’s unlikely he’d do something if he thought his father wouldn’t have wanted him to, so he probably wouldn’t choose to befriend someone below his status. Because of this, it’s likely that Goyle also didn’t have a ‘lower-class’ job.

> Much of Draco’s behaviour at school was modelled on the most impressive person he knew – his father – and he faithfully copied Lucius’s cold and contemptuous manner to everyone outside his inner circle. Having recruited a second henchman (Crabbe being already in position pre-Hogwarts) on the train to school, the less physically imposing Malfoy used Crabbe and Goyle as a combination of henchman and bodyguard throughout his six years of school life. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Draco Malfoy (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy)*</sup></sub>

It’s not said exactly what either of their jobs were, but because of the Malfoys’ willingness to associate with them, they can be presumed not to have been below a certain social status.